# How can I give the same background image to many transparent background PNGs at once?

Tags: images, png, background

I was wondering if there is a way either through Photoshop, Gimp, or some other software or website that can add an image to the background on over 100 transparent background png files at once.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in Photoshop.

1. Open one of the images.
2. Begin recording an Action, give the Action a name so you can easily find it later.
3. Add a new layer, fill it with the colour you want, and click and drag it under the image layer in the layers panel.
4. Click *Layer > Flatten Image*
5. Stop recording the Action.
6. Close the document without saving anything.
7. Now you can apply the Action you recorded to a batch of images in a folder using *File > Automate > Batch*. Choose the source folder, and an output folder, and select the Action you previously recorded, and click OK

Comment: I think we must merge the layers before stop the recording.

Comment: @LeoNas, I've added that now.

Comment: Last comment. I managed to figure it out. I had to navigate to file > place within the action. Thanks for your help.